# Interesting problem complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, branch-cuts, branch-points

Suppose that a branch of the function $f(z) = (z −1)^{\frac{2}{3}}$ is defined by means of the branch cut in Fig. 2 and that it takes the value $1$ when $z = 0$. Determine the value of $f(z)$ and of its derivative $f′(z)$ at the point $z=i$.

[image: fig. 2]
I don't know how to start?

Answer (score 1):

From the figure we take
$$i-1=\sqrt{2}e^{-i\pi/4}(0-1)\ ,$$
hence
$$f(i)=2^{1/3}e^{-i\pi/6}f(0)=2^{1/3}\left({\sqrt{3}\over2}-{i\over2}\right)\ .$$
Furthermore from $f^3(z)=(z-1)^2$ we obtain
$$3f^2(z)f'(z)=2(z-1)$$
and therefore
$$f'(i)={2(i-1)\over 3f^2(i)}=\ldots\quad.$$